# Prevent form submission in java script after displaying alert message

Tags: javascript, forms

This is my coding in js

```
    var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,12}$/;
    function validate(form) 
    {
            var Name = document.getquote.name.value;
            if (!ck_name.test(Name))
             {
                    alert("Enter a valid FirstName containing alphabets ,numbers with minimum of 3 characters");
                    document.getElementById('name').focus();
                    return false;
            }
    }
```

Iam calling this function on form submit. After showing the alert message, I want the focus to be back on the name-textbox but the page get submitted after the alert. The "return false" command is not working.

Comment: Please show us your form code.

Comment: Show to javascript code for submitting the form

Comment: you're missing a semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Asryael , I shall submit my fomr code as an answer

Comment: @Saturnix where is the semicolon missing?

Comment: My form code is

        <form method="POST" name="getquote" id="getquote" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

Comment: I got the mistake. I used the focus function with getelement by id and missed to give id

Comment: @SrinathMohan Try form.getquote.name.value instead of document.

Answer (score 1):

You add this code when false occurs

```
$('#formID').attr('onsubmit','return false');
```

Another Way

`$("form").submit(function () { return false; });` that will prevent the button from submitting or you can just change the button type to "button" `<input type="button"/>` instead of `<input type="submit"/>`

Comment: what makes you think OP can use jQuery?

Comment: there may be some error in your function thatz why it not working  well. Check whether you are getting value in variable Name and also make sure that there is an element with id name.

Answer (score 1):

@Sridhar R answer worked for me, with a little change, instead of 'onsubmit' I used 'onSubmit'

```
$('#formID').attr('onSubmit','return false');
```